# temporarily disabling foldclose=all

Tags: vim, folding

My current vim configuration is set to auto close folds once the cursor moves out from their area with:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldclose=all
```

That works really well. Therefore, I often feel the need of focus on 2 different fold section at the same time *(i.e: two `if` statements in different positions)*.

Unfortunately, the above becomes impossible with `foldclose` set to `all` considering the fact that by moving the cursor out of the first `if` clause it will make the previous to close immediately.

By any chance, is there any way to temporarily mark that fold so it won't be influenced by `foldclose=all` while I check both clauses and one finished, I can simply remove that blocking flag so it will come back to normal?

> I think that the `syntax` method is the one that serves me well since it is usually what I look for when working with language specific folding.

Comment: Not the best solution but `zR` will override `foldclose=all` until you close them again or re-open the file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Steve, the only problem is that `zR` will open all the other folds I'm afraid :/ if I could only delete the one in question it would be great indeed. Or even if there was a parameter that sets `foldclose` only for level `2` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

However, you could cheat by splitting the window (`:split`). This allows the cursor to be in a different position in each window, so you can have a different fold open in each.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the foldclose option temporarily to nothing and then set it to `all` again.

So, anywhere in the document you type:

```
:set foldclose=<CR>
```

(Nothing after the `=`)

Then you can open the folds you want to work with, and when you're done just set the option back with:

```
:set foldclose=all<CR>
```

**Extra:**

If you're folding manually then I recommend using the option:

```
set foldcolumn=1   " Or 2, 3, ...
```

to have a visual aid of where the folds begin and end, and also their depth level at the left margin of the document, next to the line number column.

[Image of my current _vimrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQQCa.png)